# Is the last button in a form automatically the submit button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm noticing some strange behavior with forms in react. I'm using a button with a handleSubmit function for the onClick attribute, but it is not technically a submit button for the form. Nevertheless, parts of the handleSubmit function are not working even when they are exactly the same lines of code from other functions. I believe the form is submitting on click of the button, but I have not designated this button as a submit button for the form. It's just a button.

```
<button
    class="button is-dark"
    onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e, listItem.album.albumid, document.getElementById('scoreNum'+ listItem.index).value, listItem.index)}
    disabled={setDisabledInputs()}
>
    Submit
</button>
```

This function works fine:

```
const onClear = (item) => {
    document.getElementById('scoreNum' + item).removeAttribute("value")
    document.getElementById('scoreRange' + item).value = document.getElementById('scoreRange' + item).defaultValue
}
```

When I use one of the same lines of code in the handleSubmit function, it doesn't work, and the page refreshes as if the form has been submitted unless I use event.preventDefault():

```
const handleSubmit = (event, albumid, rating, item) => {
    document.getElementById('scoreNum' + item).removeAttribute("value") //why doesn't this work
}
```

I would expect the handleSubmit function to just do the code I wrote and nothing else.

Comment: Any `<button>` tag is going to be a "submit" button by default, React or no. It's a good idea to always add your own explicit "type" attribute.

Comment: Every button in a form is a submit button. You have to specify `type="button"` to disable this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have one button in a `form` element, this automatically becomes the submit button, unless it is given a different type attribute.

Also, i wouldn't name the eventHandler on the button as `onSubmit`, as you don't submit the button, you submit the form. This may cause confusion as you are not handling a submit event, you are handling a click event.

What you should declare in the callback function is `e.PreventDefault()` calling the PreventDefault method stops the page from trying to complete the submit event and thus stops the page refreshing.